# SQL MAX после SQL SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

У меня есть разные таблицы, по которым я получаю итоговую цену продуктов

```
select id_pizza, sum(quantity*p.price) as total_price
from order_content o
left join pizza p on o.id_pizza = p.id
group by id_pizza
```

Как получить максимальную из этих цен вместе с id_pizza?
Максимальные цены у разных продуктов могут совпадать, тогда мне нужно получить их все.

Comment: Сортировать по убыванию, взять только первую запись.

Comment: а если несколько продуктов с одинаковой максимальной ценой?

Comment: Тогда RANK() в СТЕ.

Comment: а как это будет выглядеть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    select o.id_pizza, 
           sum(o.quantity*p.price) as total_price
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(o.quantity*p.price) DESC) rnk
    from order_content o
    left join pizza p on o.id_pizza = p.id
    group by o.id_pizza
)
SELECT id_pizza, total_price
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```